# module error on sublime text 2

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, sublimetext2

for some reason I cannot load module for BeautifulSoup on Sublime Text 2.
When I type in:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

I get the following error: ImportError: No module named bs4

I use Anacanda and it works fine on the command line and ipython notebook, but I would prefer to use Sublime Text 2.  I'm literally clueless.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sublime Text uses it's own python interpreter, not the systems. Modules you install to your system won't be visible in sublime text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sublime Text is using a different python interpreter (hence, different `site-packages` directory, different installed packages.)

You can edit the build system it uses, however. If you go into Sublime Text's packages directory and find the Python directory, there should be a file named `Python.sublime-build` and the content should be something like:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Make a copy of that file in your Sublime Text `User` directory and change `"cmd": ["python"` to be `"cmd": ["/path/to/your/python"`

Note: I don't know what platform you're on. On OS X, go to "Sublime Text 2" -> "Preferences" -> "Browse Packages" if you don't know where to find the directory.